# Background images not appearing

Tags: html, css, image

I have here my codes for html and css. I dont seem to catch the problem on why my images wont load or show-up. I tried them to load both on firefox and chrome.

My problem is not on jsfiddle.

And here is my folder structure:

- localhost/website/img
- localhost/website/css
- localhost/website

http://jsfiddle.net/p8eS3/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="description" />
        <meta name="author" content="author" />
        <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <title>Title</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div id="logo"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Body */

#body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #ccc;
}

/* Container */

#container {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}

/* Sidebar */

#sidebar {
    background: url(../img/sidebar.png) repeat-y;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

/* Logo */

#logo {
    background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
}
```

Comment: Wait, are you asking why they don't show up on ***jsfiddle***?

Comment: @Wesley Murch - I think its just a poor understanding on image urls. Don't beat down too hard on them for the jsfiddle example. It's good to see people at least providing examples!

Comment: @Curt: It's not clear what the question actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two images, they're added as background images for divs, but those divs do not have layout since the sidebar lacks height and the logo height and width. Which means they do not show up at all. Give them height/width to fix it.

If not the paths to the images are wrong.

Comment: You're actually dead-on in a way, adding content made some images appear on jsfiddle with relative paths: http://jsfiddle.net/p8eS3/3/

Comment: @Wesley: If you take a look at the fiddle in my answer, it displays some images without having to add content.

Comment: The images aren't displayed in jsfiddle since they don't exist on that server (obviously) it's just that one div (#container) has a background color. - but I think my answer is correct in his own environment.

Comment: @Spycho: Yeah it's the same exact idea - give the divs some dimensions, I just thought it was funny because I highly doubt this is OP's actual problem. Maybe he'll come back and clarify some time. **EDIT** Looks like he did.

Comment: @sg3s, (obviously), they do exist: http://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png. Go to my fiddle and hit "Run". You will see the jsFiddle logo loaded up in the bottom right pane. That's a handy coincidence :)

Answer (score 2):

The images aren't loading as jsfiddle won't recognise `../img/sidebar.png` as this will look locally on their server.

I'm assuming that this is not your initial problem though, and that you are experiencing problems getting the right path on your application.

I would recommend 'rooting' your image url so that it works from the root folder to the location like:

```
background: url(/img/sidebar.png) repeat-y;
```

Comment: Not the problem, his divs don't have layout.

Comment: Ah! Well spotted @sg3s. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

Could be your folder structure. Are the images in a folder the same level as your html file, or a level up. If they're the same level, try replacing ../images with ./images

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the images is most likely off.  This will be hard to debug via a js fiddle.  Can you post your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your divs don't actually take up any space, so you can't see any background. See [your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/p8eS3/2/) for an example of how to fix this.

Alternatively, you might want to consider using [HTML img tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a `width` and a `height` to your `#logo` element so that the BG can appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
#sidebar {
    background: url(../img/sidebar.png) repeat-y;
    width: 40px;   /* your background width */
    height:60px;    /* your background height */
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

/* Logo */

#logo {
    background: url(../img/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 40px;   /* your logo width */
    height:60px;    /* your logo height */
}
```